# What's the equivalent to patsubst in meson?

Tags: meson-build

When I need to turn a list of input files to a list of output files in a makefile I'd do something like this:

```
input := file_a.ts file_b.ts file_c.ts
output := $(input:.ts=.js)
```

How would I do this in meson? I tried using the '@BASENAME@' syntax first:

```
js = custom_target(
  'compile-ts',
  input: ts,
  command: [ tsc, '-p', tsconfig, '--outDir', '.' ],
  output: '@BASENAME@.js'
)
```

But no luck:

```
ERROR: custom_target: output cannot contain "@PLAINNAME@" or "@BASENAME@" when there is more than one input
```

I then tried the `replace()` function:

```
  ...
  output: sources.replace('.ts', '.js')
```

Alas, more errors:

```
ERROR: Unknown method "replace" in object <[ArrayHolder] holds [list]: ['main.ts', 'window.ts']> of type ArrayHolder.
```

Surprisingly, I can't find any documentation for such a basic use case.

*Edit:*
found a workaround using loops:

```
javascript = []
foreach ts: typescript
  javascript += ts.replace('.ts', '.js')
endforeach
```

But this feels rather dirty... still looking for a better way.